# Python 2.7: Popping from a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, csv

I am currently making a game like space invaders. The game will take in all the scores from the game, sort them, and then save the scores to a csv file. My method of doing this is by saving scores to an unsorted csv file, reading and sorting those values, then saving the sorted values to different sorted csv file. However, I want my csv file to only store the top 10 scores. This is the code that I currently have for this process:

```
if col:
    with open("rec_Scores.csv", "ab") as f:     #adding new score into unsorted file
        w = csv.writer(f, delimiter = ",")
        w.writerow([curr_score])


    with open ("rec_Scores.csv", "rb") as csvfile:  #reads file, converts values to integers and sorts file (including the new score)
        r = csv.reader(csvfile)
        scores = list(r)
        scores_int = [int(score[0]) for score in scores]
    bubbleSort(scores_int)
    scores_int.pop()
    print(scores_int)

    with open("srt_Scores.csv", "wb") as sortfile:   #Should write a new csv file every time containing the sorted scores
        w = csv.writer(sortfile, delimiter = ",")
        w.writerows([[v] for v in scores_int])
```

I know this isn't the most efficient method to do this process but it works mostly. If anyone could help me make the program just store the top 10 scores it would be much appreciated.

P.s:
This is my first time working with a csv file in Python so I know it is messy and inefficient, but the scores are stored and sorted fine, I just want to limit the number of values.

Comment: `pandas` can load/save csv files, with it you can easily load, add, sort and then save the top10

Comment: You need to assign `pop()` to a variable, e.g. : `s = scores_int.pop(); print(s)`

Comment: @AChampion That's only true if he cares about the value that he's popping. It's not clear from the code whether that's the case. (He may be just using it to remove the last element from the list.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the above code is otherwise "working" for you (you're able to add new scores, read and sort them), then to limit them to 10 all you need to do is slice off the first 10 scores. Replace this line:

```
scores_int.pop()
```

...with this:

```
scores_int = scores_int[:10]
```

That assumes your best scores come first. If not, then you want the *last* 10 items instead:

```
scores_int = scores_int[-10:]
```

It's safe to do this before you have 10 items in the list. In that case either of the given lines will simply do nothing.